# Components disappear when 2 or more are added to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jslider

I have created a class `SliderPanel` that allows a user to use a `JSlider` to rotate a picture and return an `int` representing the selected value on the slider. This object inherits from `JPanel`, so when I add two or more `SliderPanels` to the main `JPanel` (creationPanel), it appears that the pictures disappear from the GUI. Is there a work around for this, I have tried changing to an absolute layout, nesting panels, and resizing.

Here is the code for the `SliderPanel`:

```
public class SliderPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JSlider slider;
    private JLabel[] labelsArray;
    private static final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private int selectedValue = 5;
    private boolean isImgVisible;
    
    /**
     * Constructor which creates the JPanel and manages the changing of the 
     * JSlider.
     * 
     * @param headerTitle The title of the Panel.
     * @param window The Window object to retrieve the images from.
     */
    public SliderPanel(String headerTitle, Window window)
    {
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        
        labelsArray = window.getImages();
        
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        // Create a header for the label slider and add it to the panel.
        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("<HTML><U>" + headerTitle + 
                "</U></HTML>");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(headerLabel, gbc);
        
        Hashtable labels = new Hashtable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            labels.put(i, new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
        
        JPanel sliderAndImgPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel imgPanel = new JPanel();
        sliderAndImgPanel.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        
        slider = new JSlider(0, 10, 5);
        slider.setLabelTable(labels);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
            selectedValue = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
            System.out.println(selectedValue);
            
            if (isImgVisible)
            {
                System.out.println("in");
                sliderAndImgPanel.remove(imgPanel);
                imgPanel.removeAll();
            }
            
            validate();
            repaint();
            
            JLabel pic = labelsArray[selectedValue];
            pic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
            imgPanel.add(pic);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            sliderAndImgPanel.add(imgPanel, gbc);
            isImgVisible = true;
            validate();
            window.validate();
        });
        
        JLabel pic = labelsArray[5];
        pic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imgPanel.add(pic);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        sliderAndImgPanel.add(imgPanel, gbc);
        sliderAndImgPanel.validate();
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        sliderAndImgPanel.add(slider, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        add(sliderAndImgPanel, gbc);
    }
    
    /**
     * This method returns the value selected on the JSlider.
     * 
     * @return The selected value. [0, 10] 
     */
    public int getSelectedValue()
    {
        return selectedValue;
    }
}
```

And here is the Window class where the panels get added to the JFrame:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Window extends JFrame
{
    private static JLabel[] imagesArray;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Window();
    }
    
    public Window()
    {
        super("Testing");
        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
        setSize(1000, 700);
        setVisible(true);
        
        imagesArray = loadImages();
        
        add(new SliderPanel("test 1", this));
        add(new SliderPanel("test 2", this));
        
    }
    
    //  Accessor method.
    public static JLabel[] getImages()
    {
        return imagesArray;
    }
    
    // Loads images from project directory.
    private static JLabel[] loadImages()
    {
        JLabel[] array = new JLabel[11];

        // Load each image into the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedImage newImg = ImageIO.read(new File(i + ".png"));
                array[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(newImg));
            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + i);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here are the links to the images I uploaded:

```
https://i.imgur.com/BvIehj5.png, 
https://i.imgur.com/f527RdK.png,
https://i.imgur.com/98mgTHr.png,
https://i.imgur.com/Jsqm08U.png,
https://i.imgur.com/0pHTDgE.png,
https://i.imgur.com/TvtEiFm.png,
https://i.imgur.com/VeEDFfn.png,
https://i.imgur.com/3rp59Oz.png,
https://i.imgur.com/AjVf9pU.png,
https://i.imgur.com/sqEO7GL.png,
https://i.imgur.com/dXlush6.png
```

Comment: If you could create and post a decent [mre] this would likely help you get a decent answer quickly.

Comment: You're calling `setPreferredSize()` in several places, you should be allowing the panel to determine its own size.  That's how you get multiple components to display correctly.  I'm seconding the request for an [mcve], there's too many things here that might be wrong.  Give us some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Down-vote replaced with an up-vote.

Comment: Did you add ``slider`` to any panel? I couldn't see where.

Comment: @NomadMaker The ```slider``` gets added to the ```sliderAndImgPanel``` which then gets added to the GUI. I know that is working just fine, but for some reason something is removing the image.

Comment: @camickr I don't understand how you don't see a minimal reproducible example, I have edited the question and others saw that it was edited. Meanwhile, I was creating the example while everyone was commenting to do so.

Comment: 1) the MRE should be posted WITH the question, not updated after the fact. 2) it is not an MRE. Your question is about adding multiple "child" panels to the main JFrame. So a proper MRE would create your child panel class and simply add a JLabel to this panel. If it displays the JLabel then you have proven you understand how to add a panel to the frame. If it doesn't work, then you post the MRE. Then once it works you add another label to the child panel and retest. Once it stops working you know what you just changed and you can provide more information to your question.

Comment: Also, the image are irrelevant to the question, since we don't have access to the images. We are not going to download all the images from here just to test. Again, for the MRE you would just display the file name as text on the label, if you need multiple labels to demonstrate the problem. The point is for you to do some basic debugging by simplifying the question and the code.

Comment: @camickr I have done some basic debugging on this actually. Along with my 2 other group members, we have spent hours trying to figure this out. This also included speaking with the professor about this, who was puzzled. You seem to be what's called a "keyboard" warrior. If I didn't understand how to add a JLabel or JSlider to a JFrame, I don't think you would see all of the code above...

Comment: *we have spent hours trying to figure this out* - well, we don't have hours to look at a question. We only care about the code required to replicate the stated problem. Your question was about the missing images (JLabels). So the slider code and the ChangeListener code is completely irrelevant to the question and prevents us from having a quick glance at the code to understand what it is doing. We are providing help for you, so it is your responsibility to simplify the code as much as possible. That is the intent of the MRE. Most times the problem is actually solved by creating the MRE.

Comment: If you become a professional programmer, you will need to know how to create [mre]'s. Anytime you have a problem with a vendor's code, they will usually not look at any code that isn't a [mre].

Comment: The time to use a null layout manager is almost always **never**! LayoutMangers are there to help the programmer. I embraced them when they first appeared in java (yes, I'm that old).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static JLabel[] imagesArray;
```

You are creating a static array for a JLabel component.

Later it looks to me like you attempt to add a JLabel from the array to your panel:

```
JLabel pic = labelsArray[selectedValue];
pic.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
imgPanel.add(pic);
```

The problem is a Swing component can only have a single parent.

So by adding the JLabel to the second panel you remove it from the first panel.

Don't keep a static array of JLabels.

Instead keep a static array of `ImageIcon`. An Icon CAN be shared by multiple components.

Then when you want to add the label to the panel you create a new JLabel using the ImageIcon.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you.